# Usercontrol exception handling

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a scenario where i'm loading a control in the masterpage:

```
   Control mycontrol = LoadControl("~/mycontrol");
   aspholder.Controls.Add(MyControl);
```

Now i need to know if it is possible to catch exceptions (even for statment that do not have a try catch( that are thrown in the usercontrol from the master page

Comment: not sure if I follow. try catch blocks should be placed around where the exception is most likely to occur. So even within the usercontrol if it was doing something besides rendering data on the view/UI. you could place a try catch block around your code snippet but wouldn't quite make sense

Answer (score 1):

You can handle unhandled exceptions on [TemplateControl.Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.error%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event. MasterPage,Page,UserControl all of them inherit it, so you can write:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class MyMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Error += Page_Error;
        }

        private void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ex = Server.GetLastError();

            // do something with exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Then if unhandled exception occurs in Page\UserControl logic, then it will call Error event, that will call this Page_Error method.

MSDN article about it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed577840(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1